# Atlanta Sitecore User Group: A Lap Around the Highlights Track of Sitecore Symposium 2016

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (EST):** Thursday, November 17, 2016, 6:30 PM - 8:45 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, November 17, 2016, 23:30 - Friday, November 18, 2016, 01:45

**Location:** [City Club of Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps/place/3343+Peachtree+Rd+NE+%231850,+Atlanta,+GA+30326/@33.8468699,-84.369076,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88f50f587146262b:0x83ecc588fbb3e1ce!8m2!3d33.8468699!4d-84.3668873?hl=en), 3343 Peachtree Road Northeast #1850, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/234941799/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

After a two year hiatus the [Atlanta Sitecore User Group](https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/) will reconvene on November 17, 2017. The title of the event is *A Lap Around the Highlights Track of Sitecore Symposium 2016* and we will have speakers from [BrainJocks](http://www.brainjocks.com/), [Rightpoint](http://www.rightpoint.com/), [Arke](http://www.arke.com/), and [Perficient](http://www.perficient.com/) sharing the highlights from this year's Sitecore Symposium. We will cover hot topics such as Sitecore Publishing Service, Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA), and Sitecore Helix Principles.

This is a great opportunity to network with fellow Sitecore enthusiasts in Atlanta and learn more about Sitecore.

Comment: Added to the board.